# Http post php array in C#

Tags: c#, php, arrays, post

I am trying to build a C# form application interacts with my php web page. It makes HTTP file post to php page but php page expects an array.

If i do it in php instead of C# it seems like: (It works)

```
<?php
$postArray=array("a"=>"1","b"=>"2","c"=>3);
....
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postArray);
...
?>
```

C# code: (not working)

```
string boundary = "-----------------------------" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");
HttpWebRequest webrequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("localhost/index.php");
webrequest.CookieContainer = cookies;
webrequest.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
webrequest.Method = "POST";
webrequest.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; tr; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13";
webrequest.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
NameValueCollection n1 = new NameValueCollection();

n1.Add("a", "1");
n1.Add("b", "2");
n1.Add("c", "3");

using (var requestStream = webrequest.GetRequestStream())
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
{
    writer.Write("POST_DATA=" + n1);
}

using (var responseStream = webrequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
```

So how can i post this php array in C#? I tried hashtable and dictionary but something is wrong in it. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: show your c# code that you have (even not working)

Comment: maybe it was a typo here and not in your actual code but fyi in a php array it should be "a"=>"1" not "a"->"1"

Comment: have you checked in Fiddler.. are both of them sending same data.. if not what are the differences

Comment: I am trying to do it in C#. I tried in php. Php worked as i expected but still C# not working. We should post php array. localhost/index.php splits and uses it.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I'm not sure if this will help, but PHP takes in arrays as individual fields.

For instance, if you have the array `$some_array = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2)`, and you posted it as a GET, the URL would contain `?some_array[a]=1&some_array[b]=2`.

This should work the same in a POST request, only then it's in the body of the request, as opposed to the URL.